# Catch Block for Insert Trigger Not Firing for Error Launching SSA Job

Tags: t-sql, jobs

I'm setting up an AFTER INSERT trigger to launch an SSA job which executes a SSIS package to report on an ETL log file after its process completes. The syntax for the TRY...CATCH block appears correct but the error handling doesn't work for the error code when it detects the SSA job it's told to launch is already running.

The trigger is for a user table in a SQL Server 2012 SP4 instance (with SQL 2012 (110) compatibility). I tried handling the one error (#22022) for a SQL job already running but it seems that you can't error trap the execution of a system stored procedure.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InterfaceSupport.trg_XMLTrigger_Insert 
  ON  [InterfaceSupport].[XMLLogReaderTriggers]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Launch job'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF ERROR_NUMBER()=22022 --Job already running
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail     NULL,'name@domain.org',NULL,NULL,'Interface XML Log Reader Already     Running','The SSA Job reading Interface logs is already running. The job will     attempt to catch the new request at the end of the current cycle.'
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @Errormsg nvarchar(max)
                SELECT @Errormsg=ERROR_MESSAGE()
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail     NULL,'name@domain.org',NULL,NULL,'Interface XML Log Reader Spawn     Error',@Errormsg
            END
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

I'm getting the following error despite the error handling block. It's as if the CATCH block is non-existent.

```
Msg 22022, LeveSQLServerAgent Error: Request to run job Launch Job (from User xxx) refused because the job is already running from a request by User xxx. l 16, State 1, Line 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can't be caught by `TRY/CATCH` unfortunately.

You should check if the job is running and start only if it's not, although the job might start in between the check and the `EXEC` statement.

```
DECLARE @JobID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS J WHERE J.name = 'Launch job')

IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        'job is running'
    FROM 
        msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
    WHERE 
        ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC) AND 
        ja.start_execution_date is not null AND 
        ja.stop_execution_date is null AND
        ja.job_id = @JobID
    )
BEGIN
     EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Launch job'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail     NULL,'name@domain.org',NULL,NULL,'Interface XML Log Reader Already     Running','The SSA Job reading Interface logs is already running. The job will     attempt to catch the new request at the end of the current cycle.'
END
```